# Pasar archivo de texto a binario

Tags: c++, c

El programa lee un archivo que es un registro de las temperaturas durante el año (1988-01-01    -23ºC) y lo escribe en binario en otro archivo. No da ningún error de compilación y en el archivo binario se ve algo escrito. ¿Cómo podría saber si el programa ha funcionado correctamente? Dejo el código por si hay algún error muy evidente.

```
typedef struct{
    int year, month, day;
    float temp; 
}registro;

registro reg;
FILE* pbin;
FILE* ptxt;

int main()
{
    ptxt = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
    pbin = fopen("temp_copy.dat", "wb");
    do {
        fscanf(ptxt, "%d-%d-%d %f", &reg.year, &reg.month, &reg.day, &reg.temp);
        fwrite(&reg, sizeof(reg), 1, pbin);
    } while (!feof(ptxt) && !ferror(ptxt) && !ferror(pbin));

fclose(pbin);
fclose(ptxt);
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás preguntando si los datos se han guardado correctamente?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Exacto

Comment: Prueba a leerlos de la misma forma a ver si lees lo que escribiste.

Comment: @SuperG280 Gracias funciono! No se me habia ocurrido hacer eso

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probarlo de dos formas:

**Opción 1**

Creas una rutina que lea el archivo, así podrás comparar si los valores son los esperados:

```
registro reg;
File * file = fopen("temp_copy.dat", "rb");
fread(&reg, sizeof(reg), 1, file);

if (reg.year == ?? && /* ... */ )
```

**Opción 2**

Abres el archivo con un editor hexadecimal y extraes los datos a mano. Si haces la conversión de hexadecimal a decimal, podrás comparar los resultados.

Así, el tipo `int` ocupa típicamente 4 bytes, igual que el `float`.

La conversión de enteros es directa, los enteros suelen codificarse en complemento a dos, pero como creo que admitas enteros la conversión es directa (ojo con arquitecturas little endian)

La conversión de números en coma flotante es un poco más compleja, aquí te toca pegarte con el estándar [IEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Cualquiera de los dos métodos te deberían dar la misma solución, el segundo es obviamente más elaborado pero es igualmente válido